# vue как создать глобальную функцию?

Tags: vue.js

Vue js разделен на компоненты. но в каждом мне нужен один функционал - преобразование номера.
Как мне сделать функцию. которую я могу подтянуть к любому файлу. хоть в компонент .vue, хоть в actions.js файл.

Попробовал сделать так
создал функцию в отдельном файле /helpers/utils.js

```
function number(car) {
  // ..........
  return number;
}
export { number };
```

но при импорте в какой либо модуль

```
import { number } from '@/helpers/utils';
```

функция пустая, точнее переменная number - не определена

Получилось сделать только через главный main.js файл, где идет создание new Vue():

```
const myNumber = {
  number: (car) => {
    // ....
    return number;
  },
  install: () => {
    Object.defineProperty(Vue.prototype, 'myNumber', {
      get() { return myNumber; },
    });
  },
};
 
Vue.use(myNumber);
// ....
new Vue(...);
```

и я могу это использовать в компонентах как:

```
= this.myNumber.number(item);
```

но вот в actions.js я этой функции не вижу

Comment: возможно, я не совсем понял ситуацию, но проблем с импортом не вижу, вот пример в сандбоксе https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-test-import-hqdjr?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue, - все работает, если что доработайте его для того чтобы отобразить вашу ситуацию

Comment: Для такого используют множество разных подходов: миксины (примеси) и плагины Vue, Composition API ее же, действия Vuex, или обычную композицию через стандартные es-импорты. Выбирай любой. Здесь похоже попытка создания глобального миксина Vue (чисто предположение на основании `Vue.use`... на самом деле, непонятно что тут планировалось), но в таком случае она неправильная - как сделать правильно, объясняется в соотв. разделе документации.

Comment: В общем, из вопроса не удается понять, какой способ решения задачи в нем 
 выбран, и при чем тут вообще глобальные функции (т.к. вместо них очевидно используется композиция, и в очень странном виде) - и соотв. неясно какой ответ вообще предполагается... можно дать только общий совет изучить все обычные пути решения, перед тем как пробовать изобрести какой-то свой новый подход. Если же вопрос будет конкретизирован после изучения - посигналь, постараюсь помочь.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте написать функцию в .js и в main.js подключить через Vue.use(<global_func>) функция должна стать глобальной для всех компонентов